# Metrics available in BigQuery data from Ethereum

Tags: google-bigquery, ethereum

I want to find metrics available in BigQuery data from the Ethereum blockchain. Are any of the following available in BigQuery?

- numbers of transactions on a blockchain
- number of addresses
- different types of oracles
  possibility to count smart contracts
- number of smart contract dedicated to Chainlink

Answer (score 0):

Check out the BigQuery public datasets.

Here is a dataset for ethereum, there is also one for ethereum classic.
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/ethereum/crypto-ethereum-blockchain?project=ez-dbt-test

It includes tables for balances, blocks, logs, contracts, transactions and more.  They appear to be raw data so you would have to generate the definition of the metrics you are referring to via sql.  They do however give some examples in the link above.

One word of caution though, understand bigquery pricing before you query these tables. Some are large enough to start racking up a decent bill quickly.